# TensorFlow with 4-GPU doesn't speed up the training

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

My code first:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import where
from keras.utils import to_categorical

from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000000, centers=3, n_features=3, cluster_std=2, random_state=2)

y = to_categorical(y)

n_train = 500000
trainX, testX = X[:n_train, :], X[n_train:, :]
trainY, testY = y[:n_train], y[n_train:]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=3, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
p_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)

opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
p_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = p_model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=20, verbose=1, batch_size=32)
_, train_acc = p_model.evaluate(trainX, trainY, verbose=0)
_, test_acc = p_model.evaluate(testX, testY, verbose=0)


print("Train: %.3f, Test: %.3f" % (train_acc, test_acc))
```

The way to use the 4 powerful GPUs is this line below:

```
p_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
```

While the training is going, I can see the following (GPUs are fully utilized?):

```
(tf_gpu) [martin@A08-R32-I196-3-FZ2LTP2 mlm]$ nvidia-smi 
Wed Jan 23 09:08:24 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.79       Driver Version: 410.79       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0    49W / 250W |  21817MiB / 22919MiB |      9%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    50W / 250W |  21817MiB / 22919MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0    48W / 250W |  21817MiB / 22919MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla P40           Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   36C    P0    51W / 250W |  21817MiB / 22919MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0    114918      C   python                                     21807MiB |
|    1    114918      C   python                                     21807MiB |
|    2    114918      C   python                                     21807MiB |
|    3    114918      C   python                                     21807MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, compared to with single-GPU run, or even compared to with my Mac desktop run, it doesn't speed up at all. The total training takes about 20 minutes, almost the same as the time used by single-gpu training, and much slower than the training on my personal Mac. Why is that?

Comment: your model is too small to have any significant utilization of 1 GPU even. 
If you run model.summary() it will show you the number of parameters for your model. It would have around 350 in your case, while typical neural nets that benefit from using GPUs would have millions of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Increase your `batch_size` more than 32. Keep increasing until you have full GPU utilization. Yes, this might affect your model but it does significantly increases your performance. You will have to find a sweet spot for that batch_size.